# Restore notifications in Android when the user did not clear them

Tags: android, android-notifications

When are notifications cleared automatically in Android? Two of such instances are -

1. When the device is shut down / restarted
2. When an application is upgraded

I want to know all such cases.

Comment: What about force stop of app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications are cleared whenever the app stops.

To restore them automatically, you will want to record every notification you create (in a database perhaps) and then when they are dismissed, remove them from this list.

Whenever the app starts, you can check to see if there are any notifications that need to be re-created as they will be the ones that are still in your maintained list.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the notifications which are cleared by forceful stop will not receive delete intent?

Comment: Also, is there an even better trigger than "whenever the app starts", as I want to restore the notification even after upgrade of the app, without user intervention?

Comment: for upgrades, you can handle the intent: android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

Comment: after a reboot, you could use android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: Right, these two covers most of such cases. Will wait to see if anyone has any other perspective. Thanks lots!